# Unable to use devise_token_auth with active_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, rails-api, devise-token-auth

I'm trying to used devise_token_auth with active_admin. When running `rails g active_admin:install User` I get the following error.

#### error

> usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:578:in
>   `add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_session' 
>   You may have defined two routes with the same name using the`:as`
>   option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource
>   with the same naming.

#### routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'

  scope module: 'api' do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users, only: [:index, :show]
    end
  end

  get '/docs' => redirect('/swagger/dist/index.html?url=/apidocs/api-docs.json')
end
```

Comment: can you please share the output of `rails routes -g new_user_session`?

Comment: @WasifHossain I get the same error as above. If I remove `devise_for` I can run the server but then I can't login to active_admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by moving `mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'`
 into the api scope. The answer was right , [here](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#configroutesrb).

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  constraints subdomain: 'api'do
    scope module: 'api' do
      namespace :v1 do
        resources :users, only: [:index, :show]
        mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
      end
    end

    get '/docs' => redirect('/swagger/dist/index.html?url=/apidocs/api-docs.json')
  end
end
```

Comment: exactly! thats the way it should be done. thanks for the solution too!

Answer (score 1):

can you try a different approach by defining two controllers: one for api and the other for `active_admin`?

```
# app/controllers/api_controller.rb
# API routes extend from this controller
class ApiController < ActionController::Base
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
end

# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
# leave this for ActiveAdmin, and any other non-api routes
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
end
```

Now inherit all api controllers from `ApiController` and `ActiveAdmin` ones from `ApplicationController`.

[There is a known issue between ActiveAdmin and DeviseTokenAuth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#im-having-trouble-using-this-gem-alongside-activeadmin)

Comment: i see. let me take a deep dive into this